# Android: Connect to Website, run Javascript, wait for result, scrape

Tags: javascript, android, web-scraping, jsoup

I am looking for a way to load the HTML Data from a Website 15 seconds AFTER a Javascript function has been executed (The webpages "refreshData" Method is written in JS and needs 15 seconds  to display the Data on the Website...).

Currently I am using JSoup to observe the DOM Model. The "refreshData" Method is being called initially, so I thought JSoup would be a good pick, because I can just reconnect to the Website when I want to actualize the data on the android client. The code works perfectly, though I get an empty `div` Block returned, as the Javascript is being called after the DOM Model has been initialized. 
Now I looked around for other libraries, my Mark was on HtmlUnit. The Problem I happened to face was that it's written for the purpose of usage with Java SE. It's not fully compatible with Android as there are some dependencies missing. 
One approach Idea of me is to create an invisible Webview, load the URL and inject the Javascript Code, scrape the HTML content after 15 seconds and do the business logic with the data. My question is if that is possible? How would the performance be? 
Are there any libraries that would spare me these things and is able to do following tasks:

1. Connect to Website and maintain connection
2. execute Javascript Method
3. wait a specific amount of time and return HTML Code

Thank you alot for reading and I hope that my post crosses with someone with a helpful idea / solution / same problem like me